Code for making all fields on a UserForm required to be filled in before form submission
How can I make all fields on Excel VBA UserForm required/mandatory before it is submitted and data is entered into the corresponding worksheet?
UserForm Initialize code is below.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() ' don't change this.
         
    TPFORM.MultiPage.Value = 0
    
    Call ComboBoxValues.ComboBoxes_Items
    
End Sub

I am using an image instead of commandbutton and code of adding the data is below.
Private Sub ADDPROPERTYIMAGE2_Click()

    'TO ADD DATA IN TEXT FIELDS OF ADD PROPERTY SECTION OF THE FORM

    Dim intC As Integer
    Dim intB As Integer
    Dim Ctrl As Control      ' CREATE A CONTROL OBJECT.


    intC = addproperty.Range("A2").Value
    intB = addproperty.Range("F2").Value

    If TextBoxPROPRef.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "A REFERENCE MUST BE ASSIGNED TO THE PROPERTY WHEN ENTERING PROPERTY DETAILS. THIS FIELD CANNOT BE BLANK", vbInformation, "THY PROPERTIES"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    addproperty.Range("A" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPRef.Value
    addproperty.Range("B" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPDoor.Value
    addproperty.Range("C" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPStreet.Value
    addproperty.Range("D" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPTown.Value
    addproperty.Range("E" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPPostcode.Value
    addproperty.Range("I" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPAVALDate.Value
    addproperty.Range("L" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPRent.Value
    addproperty.Range("W" & intC + 4).Value = TXTPROPNotes.Value


    'TO ADD DATA IN COMBOBOX FIELDS OF ADD PROPERTY SECTION OF THE FORM

    addproperty.Range("F" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPStatus.Value
    addproperty.Range("G" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPType.Value
    addproperty.Range("H" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPFee.Value
    addproperty.Range("J" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPVIEWARNG.Value
    addproperty.Range("K" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPTenantType.Value
    addproperty.Range("M" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPLRoom.Value
    addproperty.Range("N" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPBRoom.Value
    addproperty.Range("O" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPKitchen.Value
    addproperty.Range("P" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPBathroom.Value
    addproperty.Range("Q" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPGarden.Value
    addproperty.Range("R" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPOfferedas.Value
    addproperty.Range("S" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxEICR.Value
    addproperty.Range("T" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxGAS.Value
    addproperty.Range("U" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxEPC.Value
    addproperty.Range("V" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxLICENSE.Value



    ' LOOP THROUGH EACH CONTROL, CHECK IF THE CONTROL IS A TEXTBOX.
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            Ctrl.Value = ""
        End If
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            Ctrl.Value = ""
        End If
    Next Ctrl
        
    ThisWorkbook.Save
            
End Sub

At the moment when image is clicked it functions as commandbutton and data is entered into the sheet successfully but all of the txtboxes and comboboxes must be filled/selected a value before the data goes to worksheet. This is the predicament.
The form is based on Multipage which holds 8 pages. When an image/button is clicked the correct sheet becomes active in the background.

I would not recommend using Image as a Button. The main problem with image is that you can't use keyboard to tab through it. You are then mouse dependant.
Now comes the part where you want to ensure every textbox and combobox is filled. Use the same loop that you are using at the end of the code...
Private Sub ADDPROPERTYIMAGE2_Click()
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    Dim PageIndex As Integer
    Dim ParentMultiPage As MultiPage
    
    '~~> Loop through all controls in the form
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        '~~> Check type of control
        Select Case TypeName(Ctrl)
            Case "TextBox"
                '~~> Check if the textbox is empty
                If Len(Trim(Ctrl.Text)) = 0 Then
                    '~~> Check if the TextBox is inside a MultiPage
                    If TypeName(Ctrl.Parent) = "Page" Then
                        PageIndex = Ctrl.Parent.Index
                        
                        Set ParentMultiPage = Ctrl.Parent.Parent
                        '~~> Activate the correct page
                        ParentMultiPage.Value = PageIndex
                    End If
                    
                    '~~> Set focus on the textbox
                    Ctrl.SetFocus
                    MsgBox "All textboxes need to have a value"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Case "ComboBox"
                '~~> Check if the ComboBox is empty
                If Ctrl.ListIndex = -1 Then
                    '~~> Check if the ComboBox is inside a MultiPage
                    If TypeName(Ctrl.Parent) = "Page" Then
                        PageIndex = Ctrl.Parent.Index
                        
                        Set ParentMultiPage = Ctrl.Parent.Parent
                        '~~> Activate the correct page
                        ParentMultiPage.Value = PageIndex
                    End If
                    
                    '~~> Set focus on the ComboBox 
                    Ctrl.SetFocus
                    MsgBox "All ComboBoxes need to have a value"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End Select
    Next Ctrl

    '~~> Rest of your code
End Sub


Thank you for providing the code. I apologies before saying what I understood from your message and what I did! I removed the existing code and pasted your code in the code and it did not worked. When click +Addproperty image the page/tab previous to this page/tab opens up and MsgBox popup is shown. Obviously it is a novice mistake/understanding. If you can kindly clarify/explain how to add the code which you provided and how & if merge it with existing code.

Your point of tab through the form is spot on but the person who will be using this mainly is even more PC literate than I and that is why a mouse "must" be used by this individual. I do appreciate that you mentioned the pros of tab. Thank you.

Thank you TinMan and JonSharpe for editing the code. Appreciate your help.

The code that I have given above checks if any textbox or combobox is empty. And if it is empty then it sets focus on the control.

Assuming that the controls in ADDPROPERTYIMAGE2_Click are all the controls that we need to validate:
Function ValidateControls() As Boolean
    Dim ControlArray As Variant

    ControlArray = Array( _
        TextBoxPROPRef, TextBoxPROPDoor, TextBoxPROPStreet, TextBoxPROPTown, TextBoxPROPPostcode, _
        TextBoxPROPAVALDate, TextBoxPROPRent, TXTPROPNotes, _
        ComboBoxPROPStatus, ComboBoxPROPType, ComboBoxPROPFee, ComboBoxPROPVIEWARNG, _
        ComboBoxPROPTenantType, ComboBoxPROPLRoom, ComboBoxPROPBRoom, ComboBoxPROPKitchen, _
        ComboBoxPROPBathroom, ComboBoxPROPGarden, ComboBoxPROPOfferedas, ComboBoxEICR, _
        ComboBoxGAS, ComboBoxEPC, ComboBoxLICENSE)
    Dim Item
    For Each Item In ControlArray
        If Len(Item.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Next
    
    ValidateControls = True
End Function

Alternatively, we can iterate over all the controls:
Function ValidateControls() As Boolean
    Dim Item As MSForms.Control
    For Each Item In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(Item)
            Case "TextBox", "CheckBox"
                If Len(Item.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                If Item.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Function
        End Select
    Next
    ValidateControls = True
End Function

Complete Example:
Option Explicit

Private Sub ADDPROPERTYIMAGE2_Click()
    If Not ValidateControls Then
        MsgBox "Please ensure all required fields are filled out before proceeding.", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'TO ADD DATA IN TEXT FIELDS OF ADD PROPERTY SECTION OF THE FORM

    Dim intC As Long
    Dim intB As Long
    Dim Ctrl As Control      ' CREATE A CONTROL OBJECT.


    intC = addproperty.Range("A2").Value
    intB = addproperty.Range("F2").Value

    If TextBoxPROPRef.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "A REFERENCE MUST BE ASSIGNED TO THE PROPERTY WHEN ENTERING PROPERTY DETAILS. THIS FIELD CANNOT BE BLANK", vbInformation, "THY PROPERTIES"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    addproperty.Range("A" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPRef.Value
    addproperty.Range("B" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPDoor.Value
    addproperty.Range("C" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPStreet.Value
    addproperty.Range("D" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPTown.Value
    addproperty.Range("E" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPPostcode.Value
    addproperty.Range("I" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPAVALDate.Value
    addproperty.Range("L" & intC + 4).Value = TextBoxPROPRent.Value
    addproperty.Range("W" & intC + 4).Value = TXTPROPNotes.Value


    'TO ADD DATA IN COMBOBOX FIELDS OF ADD PROPERTY SECTION OF THE FORM

    addproperty.Range("F" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPStatus.Value
    addproperty.Range("G" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPType.Value
    addproperty.Range("H" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPFee.Value
    addproperty.Range("J" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPVIEWARNG.Value
    addproperty.Range("K" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPTenantType.Value
    addproperty.Range("M" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPLRoom.Value
    addproperty.Range("N" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPBRoom.Value
    addproperty.Range("O" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPKitchen.Value
    addproperty.Range("P" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPBathroom.Value
    addproperty.Range("Q" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPGarden.Value
    addproperty.Range("R" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxPROPOfferedas.Value
    addproperty.Range("S" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxEICR.Value
    addproperty.Range("T" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxGAS.Value
    addproperty.Range("U" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxEPC.Value
    addproperty.Range("V" & intB + 4).Value = ComboBoxLICENSE.Value

    ' LOOP THROUGH EACH CONTROL, CHECK IF THE CONTROL IS A TEXTBOX.
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            Ctrl.Value = ""
        End If
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            Ctrl.Value = ""
        End If
    Next Ctrl
        
    ThisWorkbook.Save
            
End Sub

Function ValidateControls() As Boolean
    Dim Item As MSForms.Control
    For Each Item In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(Item)
            Case "TextBox", "CheckBox"
                If Len(Item.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                If Item.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Function
        End Select
    Next
    ValidateControls = True
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() ' don't change this.
         
    TPFORM.MultiPage.Value = 0
    
    Call ComboBoxValues.ComboBoxes_Items
    
End Sub


That is correct TinMan, the controls in ADDPROPERTY need to be validated. I tried the first code and added a module and called it in. It returned runtime error and on debug it says line if less than 0 then exit. Object required.

The Validation functions need to be in the userform.

OK, I tried to add the second code for all controls in userform but I under general or initialize function? I am sorry for an extremely silly question. VBA keep throwing error at compile stage.

Probably Siddhart code is correct too but it is me who don't know his way around VBA code editor....

I edited my post to include a complete example @Tee.

@Tee Watch: Excel VBA Introduction Part 1 - Getting Started in the VB Editor  and Excel VBA Introduction Part 21 - User Forms.  IMO, this is the best tutorial series on YouTube.

Thank you and I added the code and new error was in UserForm Initialize function. I deleted it (not sure if I should have nor not because the code was not executing), and now even after all fields are filled, the MsgBox continues to warn that all fields must be filled in.  So it does work but not quite there yet. Also, when I try to copy and paste with Option Explicit line it does not copy it in the ADDPROPERTY code section but Option Explicit goes to the Sub on top of ADDPROPERTY. It is weird I think.

I will watch those videos Thank you very much for your help and time. I appreciate it.

@Tee Here is the test form that I created: Userform Required Fields.xlsm.  You'll have to download it to use it.

you won't believe my luck, it works in your sheet but doesn't in mine. The window keeps giving informative message that don't discuss in here and move to chat, which I cannot do. So I should avoid adding comments now and figure out what is wrong with me or the code in general in my project which is making this not work. I do appreciate you and Siddhart Rout taking time to write the code, explain in detail. Thank you.

If you case remove the sensitive information and add a download link, I'll look at it for you.  Alternatively,  you can export the Userform and link me the two exported files.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Tee Here is another link which covers Visual Basic Editor in detail...

Thank you @SiddharthRout for the link. Your help is appreciated.
